# viewscoped bean doesn't save session parameter

Tags: jsf-2

I have a page with datatable with product information from which at a product selection action I redirect to product info page passing a parameter:

```
configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("productInfo?faces-redirect=true&prId=" + selectedCpl.getP().getPrId());
```

In my viewscoped bean in my init method I get the request parameter and fill the objects needed:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductInfo implements Serializable {

private Product p;
private Integer prId;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if (request.getParameter("prId") != null) {
        prId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("prId"));
        p = pf.find(prId);
```

On my productInfo.xhtml I have a product info view and a dialog to edit the product info but when I press submit my the request parameter is null:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="button-edit" value="Submit" actionListener="#{productInfo.saveProduct()}" update="prodInfo" oncomplete="dlg.hide();"/>
```

I'm using jsf 2.0 with primefaces elements.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a session parameter. That's a **request** parameter. That it's `null` is because you are not sending it along with the submit request. Send it by `<f:param>`.

```
<p:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="prId" value="#{productInfo.prId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are several other potential problems. First, the view scoped bean should *not* be recreated when you submit the form. Perhaps you're using tag handlers in the view. Second, you should absolutely avoid hauling the raw `javax.servlet` API from under the JSF covers as much as possible. Use `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` instead. Third, the `<f:viewParam>` is much cleaner than that postconstruct. Fourth, redirecting by a navigation handler smells like a design problem in the view, e.g. why not use just a GET link?

The in-depth explanations on all of those issues are available in [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html).

Comment: Thank you..Yes that was the case but even with the parameter the object is recreated and couldn't save the changes. I used another approach and made my bean sessionscoped and on the list page before every redirect to productinfo page I destroyed the session object    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("productInfo"); ...only way to make it work...about the other sugestions... I don't understand why my viewscoped bean is reconstruct on ajax request... and i need postconstruct to fill like  10 objects I'm using for the view

Comment: Read the "unrelated" note. The view scoped bean should not be recreated and you should use `<f:viewParam>`. Detailed explanations/solutions/examples are already available behind the given link. Using the session scope is not a solution, but a hack/workaround.

Comment: I read the whole article and it helped me improve some parts of the code. I'm using p:datatable and an p:ajax request on select - redirect and that is the only way I can redirect.I don't understand is after I do the redirect my productList viewscoped bean gets reconstructed again...and it's a bit slow. Also you were right I am using tags first of all I have to use template so I am using <ui:composition> for including the template in the xhtmls and <ui:include> for the content part. This is my first JSF application I realy want to get it right. Thank you very much for your help.